# Is there some way to clean the maven dependencies?

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I am working in a Maven project which has about 250 jar dependencies. Approximately Four out of five dependecies are not direct dependencies, I mean, they are dependencies of our dependencies (i.e jasperreport has about 8 dependencies).

Also, I suspect that there are some jar which we don't need to the project because they were old dependencies of old tool that we needed in the past but they were replaced by others.

What I need is:

- To **detect** what jars of my `pom.xml` are not needed by the
  project.
- A way of removing the indirect jars from my `pom.xml`.

*Note: I'd swear that some time ago I manage to the indirect jars were downloaded by the direct dependencias, but I can't find how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're after [`mvn dependency:analyze`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/analyze-mojo.html):

> Analyzes the dependencies of this project and determines which are: used and declared; used and undeclared; unused and declared.

This will let you remove any dependency which is not directly used from your pom. The dependencies that are used will still bring in their transitive (indirect) dependencies, as required.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure if you need to remove some dependencies of any of your direct dependencies or just want to clean jars downloaded.

If your problem is the first one, you can use "exclude" for that dependencies -> http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html

If it's the second one, just remove your .m2/repository content and rebuild again your project

Comment: I just updated my question to meke more clear my goals.